# View Javascript calls as they happen?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, javascript-debugger

I've inherited a pretty large project and I'm trying to track down an annoying bug, but for the life of me I can't find where this specific action is getting called and executed.  Is there any way to view Javascript calls as they happen?  I can pause execution in Firebug but it always stops at an addDomListenerOnce call.

Comment: If you can find where in the code the action is happening, you can place a breakpoint there, and then look at the stack trace to see where the call come from.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't find where in the code the action is happening.

Comment: So what do you call "this specific action" ? How is it defined ? There are gazillions method calls in any application and they happen much too fast for you to see them all.

Comment: Maybe you want to see what events that are triggered? I once wrote at function that replaced addEventListener with my own, so I could log every event that was triggered. I think someone has made a library for that, but I don't remember the name. But you should also handle code that is triggered via setTimeout and setInterval.

Answer (score 4):

you can add this line

```
debugger;
```

where you want. For example as the first line of the function you want to check if it's executed. This will halt the execution of the script and you can inspect everything in firebug.

Comment: [genuine question, not a critic] Is that cross browser ? Where is it defined ?

Comment: @dystroy don't know if it's totally cross browser, would have to check, but it surely works with Firebug / Firefox ( which the poster is using )

Comment: It is defined in [ECMA262-5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) 12.15 "Evaluating the DebuggerStatement production may allow an implementation to cause a breakpoint when run under a debugger. If a debugger is not present or active this statement has no observable effect." According to [this blog entry](http://planet.openbravo.com/?p=32334) it works in Firefox with firebug, IE8 and Chrome 9.

Answer (score 2):

With Opera's Dragonfly you have the option "Break on first statement of a new script" (Thanks, @some)

It's the fifth button at top left corner.

Comment: The exact title is "Break on first statement of a new script" (in Opera 12.02)

Answer (score 1):

All modern browsers offer debugging functions.

Look for example at the [Chrome Developer tools debbuging functions](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts). It's very easy to set breakpoints and to trace the execution line after line. Of course you have the call stack so you see where the function is called from.